# Saving Fragment State gives error: int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onsaveinstancestate

I am trying to save the state of two fragments. I want them to redisplay when I change the language of the android device (when I leave the activity and come back). Those two fragments are declared as attributes of the activity and both extends the ***android.support.v4.app.Fragment*** class.  This is what I do to save them in the activity displaying them:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    if(settingsFragment.isAdded())
        this.getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState,settingsFragment.TAG,settingsFragment);
    if(historyFragment.isAdded())
        this.getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState,historyFragment.TAG,historyFragment);
}
```

This is how they are retrieved (keep in mind that this is method is called in the onCreate() method, just after the setContentView() method) :

```
private void instantiateFragments(Bundle inState) {
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    if (inState != null) { //the line 254 is just below          
        settingsFragment = (SettingsFragment) this.getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(inState, SettingsFragment.TAG);
        historyFragment = (HistoryFragment) this.getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(inState, HistoryFragment.TAG);
    } else {
        settingsFragment = SettingsFragment.newInstance("Settings","0");
        historyFragment = HistoryFragment.newInstance("History","1");
    }
}
```

This is the error that I receive when I'm trying to load back the activity:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.UI.Activities.ExampleActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2802)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2867)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4594)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:181)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1482)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6134)
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment(FragmentManager.java:872)
                                                            at com.example.UI.Activities.ExampleActivity.instantiateFragments(ExampleActivity.java:254)
                                                            at com.example.UI.Activities.ExampleActivity.onCreate(ExampleActivity.java:102)
                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2746)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2867) 
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4594) 
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:181) 
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1482) 
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6134) 
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Can you guys please help me to understand what is going on, and how can I solve this (meaning, how can I save the instance of a fragment from it's activity). Thank you

**EDIT**
For those asking me to show and hide, to display the settingsFragment, this is the method that I use:

```
protected void displayFragmentSettings() {
    FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if (settingsFragment.isAdded()) { // if the fragment is already in container
        ft.show(settingsFragment);
    } else { // fragment needs to be added to frame container
        ft.add(R.id.body, settingsFragment, "Settings");
    }
    // Hide fragment B
    if (historyFragment.isAdded()) { ft.hide(historyFragment); }
    // Hide fragment C
   // if (fragmentC.isAdded()) { ft.hide(fragmentC); }
    // Commit changes
    ft.commit();
}
```

I do the same for any other Fragment that I need to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem was that I had forgotten to add the super.onSaveInstanceState(...) method:

```
 @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //this.getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, myFragment.TAG, myFragment);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of saving the instance of a fragment, why don't you hide the first fragment and add the second fragment instead of replacing it. When you want to show the first one, call show on the first fragment and hide on the second fragment.

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(fragment1).commit();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(fragment2).commit();

Comment: I already do that when I want to switch from a fragment to another. Here, I want to for example, press the center bottom button to go come to the main page of an android device, change the language in the options, press the left button and select my app. If it was an activity it would have reload with no problem. I'm trying to achieve the same with a fragment

Comment: The fragments are meant to retain the instance of the fragment attached to the activity. If I understand correctly, you press home button and go to of the app and then from recent apps select your app. You don't have to do anything. It should resume from the same point you left of. You can always use setRetainInstance(true) on a fragment.

Comment: Can you tell me how and where to use setRetainInstance(true), so far I wasn't able to find.

Comment: You can call this on your onActivityCreated method. Go through this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)